# Razor Component vs Razor Page

Tags: razor, blazor, razor-pages

In the menu of visual studio, there are two options, `Razor Component`, and `Razor Page`, If one adds `@page` directive on the top of the razor component, it has its own address.

So what is the difference between them in practice?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Introduction

When you start a dotnet web app, you can choose between several types of apps, among them, mvc, webapp and Blazor:

```bash
dani@localhost ~ $ dotnet new
Templates                                         Short Name               Language          Tags                  
--------------------------------------------      -------------------      ------------      ----------------------
Razor Page                                        page                     [C#]              Web/ASP.NET           
...
Blazor Server App                                 blazorserver             [C#]              Web/Blazor            
Blazor WebAssembly App                            blazorwasm               [C#]              Web/Blazor/WebAssembly
...
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                      [C#], F#          Web/MVC               
ASP.NET Core Web App                              webapp                   [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages   
...
```

If you create a `webapp` you can see razor pages:

```bash
dani@localhost pp2 $ tree
.
├── appsettings.Development.json
├── appsettings.json
├── obj
│   ├── ...
├── Pages
│   ├── Error.cshtml                <-- Razor Page
│   ├── Error.cshtml.cs             <-- Razor Page
│   ├── Index.cshtml
│   ├── Index.cshtml.cs
│   ├── Privacy.cshtml
│   ├── Privacy.cshtml.cs
│   ├── Shared
│   │   ├── _Layout.cshtml
│   │   └── _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml
│   ├── _ViewImports.cshtml
│   └── _ViewStart.cshtml
├── ...
```

Quoting [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio):

> Razor Pages can make coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive than using controllers and views.

As you can see on tree structure, a razor page is a `cshtml` file (template) plus a `cs` file (behavior). The page is rendered as html and send to navigator.

Exists another kind of apps, blazor.  Quoting [Introduction to ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> Blazor is a framework for building **interactive** client-side web UI with .NET

Important term "interactive", not only render html, is a language to make page interactive (no just render html on server and send it to client)

#### Razor Component vs Razor Page

- Razor page is typically to generate an html page on server and send to client on a ASP.NET Core Web App
- Razor component ("Blazor Component") is a component for a Blazor app (can run in Blazor Server App and also in Blazor WebAssembly App) intended for interactive usage.

#### Notes

- Check [Henk's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65788980/842935), the term "Razor Component" has no logic, in Henk's opinion (and mine) should be "Blazor Component" because it runs only on Blazor apps.
- Razor components vendors named this components as "Blazor Components" : https://www.syncfusion.com/blazor-components ,  https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui, ...
- Notice that when you add `@page` directive to a Blazor component it becomes enroutable (like a "blazor page"), but it is still a component.
- You can add both Razor Components ("Blazor Components") and Razor pages to a webapp: [Using Blazor Components In An Existing MVC Application](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/) by Chris Sainty.

Comment: thank you for your answer completion with other answers. I cant find g.cs in my debug output project, I'm using .net 5.0

Comment: @HappyDeveloper  With file explorer, in your project folder, check into `obj/Debug/Razor/...`

Comment: I've created an empty razor page, and there is no Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase in its g.cs file.. @dani

Comment: public class Pages_Test : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page

Comment: Check answer: _"But **your assistant is talking about a Razor page** (not enroutable Blazor component). Razor page is part of Model-View-Controller MVC architecture."_

Comment: so what do you mean by blazor page( which is the same as blazor component)?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper. I mean that a blazor page is a blazor component with `@page` directive, because this, blazor page is still a blazor component, if you check `g.cs` you can see a blazor component with a `page` directive still inherits from `ComponentBase`. You should to diferenciate between `blazor page` ( blazor architecture) and `razor page` (MVC architecture)

Comment: so please delete or move your first line (because it is not my question and it makes your answer ambiguous) then i accept your answer

Comment: I will rewrite the whole answer to clarify and match the question.

Answer (score 9):

**Razor Component** is the illogical template name for a **Blazor Component**, in a `.razor` file.

A **Blazor Page** is a **Blazor Component** (.razor) that has a `@page "/..."` directive.

Note that the icons are correct. Just go for the purple Bl@zor thing.

Comment: no we can add @page to razor component. and in my visual studio, blazor page is created with .cshtml

Comment: No, Razor pages are placed in `.cshtml`  and can (must) have an `@page` without a route.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper, I guess that what Henk says is the term "Razor Component" exists (also present on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) but the term has no logic, the right name maybe "blazor component". All components vendors and projects are referring to components as "Blazor Components".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comparison of the features between the two:

|  | Razor Page | Razor Component |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Page Model | You can define page @model, strongly typed view | Can't define @model-- but you can define multiple classes in @code{} block then bind to your html elements |
| Event handling | Comes with .cs file where you can define OnGet, OnPost http events-- but these events by default will require page reload | You can use the @code{} block to handle page events; OnClick, OnInitialize, OnParameterSet, OnAfterRender-- events like OnClick doesn't require page reload |
| @code block | code block is only ran upon page render | code block can be used throughout the page life cycle depending on the events you defined (OnClick, OnKeyDown, etc) |